# Flutter Dropdown Button error: The argument type 'void Function(String)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(String?)?

Tags: string, flutter, dropdown

I am trying to use a drop down for my flutter app but I always get the error

> The argument type 'void Function(String)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(String?)?'.

```
Widget _lineOfBusinessRow(){
return Container(
   width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      DropdownButton<String>(
        value: _lineOfBusinessValue,

        onChanged: (String value){
          setState(() {
            _lineOfBusinessValue = value;
          });
        },

        items: _lineOfBusinessItems.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((value){
          return DropdownMenuItem(child: Text(value),
          value: value);
        }).toList(),
      )
    ],
  )
);
```

}

This is my code at the moment and this is the screenshot of the error:

[image: Error Message]

Other than that, I have also tried doing this:

```
onChanged: (String? value){
          setState(() {
            _lineOfBusinessValue = value!;
          });
        },
```

If I remove the String or the question mark, I would be prompted to add a null check to 'value' and that leads to this error:

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 0):

ITs working fine on dart pad. Have you enabled null safety etc.

https://dartpad.dev/?id=09ff2fd78405f736d63cab4de22f4eec

Comment: I am using Android Studio and I have it disabled. Should I enable it?